# Java 3.0 get distinct values from a column mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am really struggling here and have looked at other questions but just cant seem to get the answer I need.

What I am trying to do is pull through all the unique values of a column and then iterate through them and add them to an array. Ending up with the one column being stored in my array, but one of each value that exists not the multiple like there currently is.

Every time I try and do .distinct it asks me for the return class I have tried many different class but it just doesn't seem to work... Code is below any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static void MediaInteraction() {
    //Storing data from MediaInteraction in MediaArray
    //BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    //Query.put("consumerid", "");



    MongoCursor<Document> cursormedia = collectionmedia.distinct("consumerid", (What do I put here?)).iterator();

    while (cursormedia.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursormedia.next());
        MediasessionID.add(cursormedia.next());

    }
    System.out.println("Media Array Complete");
    System.out.println(MediasessionID.size());
}
```

Comment: what is `collectionmedia` a collection of? also what version of mongodb client are you using to check the usage..

Comment: It is a collection of application interactions, its a task given to me from my university. I need to pull out if the file the unique consumer id's, Excel already tells me out of the 500k rows I should get an answer of 1042 but I need to be able to do that through java linking it with the mongo collection. I use version 3.2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change that you probably want to introduce shall be somewhat like -

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursormedia = collectionmedia.distinct("consumerid",
      <ConsumerId-DataType>.class).iterator(); //please replace the consumerId field's datatype here
```

Also from the [docs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#distinct-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) -

```
/**
 * Gets the distinct values of the specified field name.
 *
 * @param fieldName   the field name
 * @param resultClass the class to cast any distinct items into.
 * @param <TResult>   the target type of the iterable.
 * @return an iterable of distinct values
 * @mongodb.driver.manual reference/command/distinct/ Distinct
 */
<TResult> DistinctIterable<TResult> distinct(String fieldName, Class<TResult> resultClass);
```

So in your example, if you are trying to attain cursor for `Document` you probably want to use `Document.class` in the above suggested code.

***Edit -*** Also the fact that you are calling `cursormedia.next()` twice the count of your `MediasessionID` would be halved. Suggest you do that(`.next`) once improving it further to obtain results.

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked this time: MongoCursor<Document> cursormedia = collectionmedia.distinct("consumerid", String.class).iterator(); Thank you! Although it gives me a result of 521 and I know the result is 1042, so I am getting exactly 1/2, can you see any reason why this might be? Thanks!

Comment: `cursormedia.next()` called twice in your logic. One inside the print statement. Just try and comment that out to see correct details.